# How can I save class variables in swift?

Tags: swift, variables, core-data, save

I have class:

```
class Dream {
    var name: String?
    var timeStamp = Date()
}
```

And I want to save all it's variables

I'm trying to save in **UserDefaults** - but It's wrong way

I think it should saved in **CoreData**, but I don't know how to do that, someone can help me?

```
var item: [Dream] = []

func addItem(nameItem: Dream) {
    item.append(nameItem)
}

func removeItem(at index: Int){
    item.remove(at: index)
}
```

I'm using func addItem in IBAction

```
@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let image = categoryImage.image
        let data = image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)!
        let date = Date()
        let name = date.description
        do {
            let documentDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:false)
            let fileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(name)

            try data.write(to: fileURL)

            print(fileURL)

        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        let dream = Dream()
        dream.timeStamp = date
        dream.name = nameTextField.text

        addItem(nameItem: dream)
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: Look at this clip and you will know everything you need.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OYRo3i9z-lM

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really be saving image data in CoreData or UserDefaults (the latter is just a .plist file), as images tend to be large in file size.

You would be better off saving `String(?)` values for the image, say as an optional `imageUrlString`, and have an optional computed `var imageUrl: URL?` from it. The image can then be retrieved when the app loads or when required (e.g. using the `PINRemoteImage` [[github page]](https://github.com/pinterest/PINRemoteImage)).

Below is a `UserDefaults` example where you have just one, but you could store a dictionary of `Dream` components (or use something like `Realm` [[docs]](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/index.html) or `CoreData` [[docs]](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata) to store more complete `Dream` instances)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import PINRemoteImage

class Dream {
    var imageUrlString: String?
    var name: String?
    var timeStampString: String = ""

    init(fromUserDefaults: Bool) {
        if fromUserDefaults {
            self.imageUrlString = StorageService.instance.imageUrlString
            self.name = StorageService.instance.nameString
            self.timeStampString = StorageService.instance.timeStampString
        }
    }
}

extension Dream {
    var imageUrl: URL? {
        guard let imageUrlString = imageUrlString else { return nil }
        return URL(string: imageUrlString)
    }

    var timeStamp: Date? {
        //Insert logic here to return a date in the desired format, from the timeStampString - e.g.
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") //For example
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" //For example

        guard let dateFromString = formatter.date(from: timeStampString) else { return nil }
        return dateFromString
    }
}

//Create a singleton to handle access to userDefaults safely

class StorageService {
    //MARK: Singleton
    static let instance = StorageService()

    //MARK: Private initialiser
    private init() {}

    private enum UserDefaultsKeys: String {
        case imageUrlString
        case nameString
        case timeStampString
    }

    var imageUrlString: String? {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.imageUrlString.rawValue) ?? nil
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.imageUrlString.rawValue)
        }
    }

    var nameString: String? {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.nameString.rawValue) ?? nil
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.nameString.rawValue)
        }
    }

    var timeStampString: String {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.timeStampString.rawValue) ?? ""
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.timeStampString.rawValue)
        }
    }

}
```

Then you can use `pin_setImage` (or something else) to load the image from the dream instance wherever it is required, for example:

```
var imageView: UIImageView = {
    let img = UIImageView()
    img.pin_setImage(from: yourDreamInstance.imageUrl)
    return img
}()
```

Comment: I do not understand how I can associate my save function with this code?

Comment: Well, your save button wasn't present in your original question when I posed this answer. In this case you would store the state in `StorageService` as follows:

`StorageService.instance.timeStampString = date(converted to string)`
`StorageService.instance.nameString = nameTextField.text`
`StorageService.instance.imageUrlString = (whatever you defined the url to the image, as a string)`

Comment: my mistake. Can you add a specific example regarding  my cod?